# Undefined reference in AVX-512

Tags: c, intrinsics, icc, avx512

I have a C code that runs on Xeon Phi, containing many AVX-512 intrinsics.

The code compiles well, until the following lines:

```
#ifdef __MIC__
__m512i mm_idx = _mm512_set_epi32(0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);
__m512 mm_temp1 = _mm512_set1_ps(temp1);
__m512 mm_temp2 = _mm512_set1_ps(temp2);
__m512i mm_temp3 = _mm512_cvttps_epi32(_mm512_fmadd_ps(_mm512_cvtepi32_ps(mm_idx), mm_temp2, mm_temp1));
#else    something else
```

The compiler gives out the following error:

```
undefined reference to '_mm512_cvt_roundepi32_ps' 
undefined reference to '_mm512_cvtt_roundps_epi32'
```

My first question is, why did the compiler convert `_mm512_cvttps_epi32` and `_mm512_cvtepi32_ps` into `_mm512_cvtt_roundps_epi32` and `_mm512_cvt_roundepi32_ps` ?

The second question is, why these intrinsic functions in particular are undefined? 
I have the following includes at the top:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <zmmintrin.h>
```

I am using icc (ICC) 15.0.1 20141023

Comment: Have you followed these symbols (eg `_mm512_cvtepi32_ps`)to their definitions?  It could be that the #define used to create these symbols, assigns them to an undefined symbol, or one that resides in a header file you have not yet included.  ***[Look here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-03/msg00773.html)***

Comment: You are right. They are defined in zmmintrin.h as: 
    `#define _mm512_cvtepi32_ps(v) _mm512_cvt_roundepi32_ps((v), _MM_FROUND_CUR_DIRECTION)`

But I still don't get why the `_mm512_cvt_roundepi32_ps` is undefined. They should be defined in ICC even if they aren't in GCC

Comment: You can't use AVX-512 intrinsics on KNC Xeon Phi, you should use KNC intrinsics instead. https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Comment: Thank you @IlyaVerbin. I actually didn't notice this. I wonder though, why isn't all the AVX512 instructions implemented in KNC?

Comment: KNC hardware was released in 2012, while the AVX-512 instruction set was only announced in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

AVX-512 instruction set was introduced in 2013 by Intel and Intel Knights Landing (KNL) hardware will support this instruction set. Latest version of Intel(R) C++ Compiler already supports generating code targeting AVX-512. More information on Intel Knights Landing project is available at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/what-disclosures-has-intel-made-about-knights-landing.